# React State Not Being Overwritten

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which initializes a state as shown below:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    // initialize the parent class which is Component
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      currentTripName : "",
      pendingTrips : [],
      completedTrips : []
    }

  }
```

Now, let's say in button click event I assign the state like this:

```
addButtonPressed() {

    this.setState({
   foo : "Hello World" 
})

}
```

Does that mean all the other state properties like

```
  currentTripName : "",
          pendingTrips : [],
          completedTrips : []
```

will be removed.

I checked and they are not being removed. If they are not being removed then why do people sometimes use the following syntax to copy the properties

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state, 
  foo : "Hello World" 

})
```

Comment: To that the previous value of this.state wouldn't change. Immutability of state is needed for Redux to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.setState` takes a *partial state update* as argument. That means that whatever you give to setState will be merged with the current state.

Using the spread operator in that way is the same as not using it. But if you have a state update that depends on the previous state you should use the callback form of setState, to avoid bugs

```
this.setState((prevstate, props) => ({...prevstate, foo: "Foo" }))
```

Comment: I think this answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> When you call setState(), React merges the object you provide into the
>   current state.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged

The merging is shallow, so foo is replaced and all other states maintain their property values.

The functional form of `setState` should be used when:

> Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you
>   should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

```
this.setState(prevState=>({loading: !prevState.loading}));
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

i noticed it too, this syntax is error prone... i think people are confused with the correct syntax, what looks like:

```
 this.setState((prevState, props)=>({
  ...prevState, 
  foo : "Hello World" 
}))
```

more about setState:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe the question was about why some people use the spread operator at all when setting state

Answer (score 0):

You just don't need the spread operator. Just set the key you need. I think the people who do that are worried about mutation, but that's not an issue here. This isn't redux. `setState` takes care of a lot for you.

Comment: The question is that if I even use setState and pass a new object, why does it not remove or override the previous state values.

Comment: Ah, I understand. That's just the way `setState` works, it only updates the keys that you pass into it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not needed, it always keep the other properties the same, the spread operator not relevant here.
if you want to change the state properties or deelte them then you should use Object.Assign() and then save it to your state